JUnit test cases skipped for a specific class despite proper setup in Gradle and Java version
I am working on an end-to-end testing class for my Java project using JUnit 5. However, only the test cases in a specific test class are being skipped, even though other test cases in the project run successfully.
Environment:
Java version: 23.0.1 (2024-10-15)
Build tool: Gradle
JUnit version: 5.7.0
Source compatibility: Java 14 (set in build.gradle)
Problem:
The test cases in CarSimulationE2ETest are skipped, but other test classes in the project execute correctly. I added debug println statements in the @BeforeEach setup method and observed the following:
Debug messages before System.setOut() appear.
No debug output after System.setOut() in the setup.
The skipped test cases don’t throw errors but simply don’t run.
Code:
Here is my test class:
package carsimulation;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class CarSimulationE2ETest {

    private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private final PrintStream originalOut = System.out;
    private final InputStream originalIn = System.in;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
        System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream("".getBytes())); // Ensure input stream is set up
        originalOut.println("Setup complete. Output redirection set.");
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() {
        String output = outContent.toString();
        originalOut.println("Captured Output:\n" + output); // Debugging information
        System.setOut(originalOut);
        System.setIn(originalIn);
        originalOut.println("Teardown complete. Output redirection reset.");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSingleCarSimulation() {
        String input = "10 10\n1\nA\n1 2 N\nFFRFFFFRRL\n2\n2";
        System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes()));

        originalOut.println("Starting testSingleCarSimulation..."); // Debugging information
        try {
            Main.main(new String[]{});
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(originalOut); // Print any exceptions to the original System.out
        }
        originalOut.println("Finished testSingleCarSimulation..."); // Debugging information

        String output = outContent.toString();
        originalOut.println("Captured Output:\n" + output); // Debugging information
        assertTrue(output.contains("Main.main started"));
        assertTrue(output.contains("Main.main finished"));
        assertTrue(output.contains("Your current list of cars are:\n- A, (5,4) S"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testMultipleCarSimulation() {
        String input = "10 10\n1\nA\n1 2 N\nFFRFFFFRRL\n1\nB\n7 8 W\nFFLFFFFFFF\n2\n2";
        System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes()));

        originalOut.println("Starting testMultipleCarSimulation..."); // Debugging information
        try {
            Main.main(new String[]{});
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(originalOut); // Print any exceptions to the original System.out
        }
        originalOut.println("Finished testMultipleCarSimulation..."); // Debugging information

        String output = outContent.toString();
        originalOut.println("Captured Output:\n" + output); // Debugging information
        assertTrue(output.contains("Main.main started"));
        assertTrue(output.contains("Main.main finished"));
        assertTrue(output.contains("A, collides with B at (5,4) at step 7"));
        assertTrue(output.contains("B, collides with A at (5,4) at step 7"));
    }
}


I suspect the issue might be related to how my code handles input. Specifically, I have a method in the InputOutputHandler class that reads input using Scanner. This method might be interfering with the System.in override in my tests.
Here is the getInput method from the InputOutputHandler class:
public String getInput() {
    try {
        if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String input = scanner.nextLine().trim();
            System.out.println("Read input: " + input); // Debugging information
            return input;
        } else {
            System.out.println("No more input available"); // Debugging information
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No line found");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out); // Print any exceptions to System.out
        throw e;
    }
}

